# dyld fatal error when running on a device

Tags: ios, thread-safety, breakpoints, fatal-error, dyld

When running my app on my external device, I get the following error:

```
0 dyld_fatal_error
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x120049088)
```

Output:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>         Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AF677AE7-E8E7-44D1-87B5-D359FE9E6598/GymAmigo.app/GymAmigo
>         Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>           /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AF677AE7-E8E7-44D1-87B5-D359FE9E6598/GymAmigo.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AF677AE7-E8E7-44D1-87B5-D359FE9E6598/GymAmigo.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
>       (lldb)

Comment: Are you targeting the correct SDK? Under build settings, make sure that the base SDK you're using is >= than the one installed on your device. So if your device is running iOS 9.3, make sure you're targeting the latest iOS.

Comment: @dirkgroten i just look at that and my base sdk is 9.3 and my device is running iOS 9.3.1, I just ran it again and the error still happens.

Comment: Remembered having this issue once a while back. Something to do with certificates actually. Does this run fine on the Simulator but not on the device?

Comment: How about reinstalling the WWDR CA, that resolved it for me if I remember correctly: [https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/43547#43547]

Comment: having the same error here, I'll try your suggestions and let you know